# When did Ahsoka follow the ways of the Force/Jedi after her departure from the order?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force, the-clone-wars, star-wars-rebels

Learning the ways of the Force is different from learning the ways of the Jedi. Initiates to both the Jedi and the Sith learn the former. The Jedi way is about the philosophy of one’s relation to the Force, and how to master control of it.

When Ahsoka left the Jedi Order, I guess we can say she was free to renounce the Jedi way in part or in whole: Clearly she lost faith in it, and decided to “find her own way”. My *personal opinion* is that it means reflecting on and coming to terms with the Jedi way and its code, continuing to practice what she agrees with and renouncing what she doesn’t.

However, there are examples of Jedi (in various continuities) who left the Order and renounced the Force completely, choosing to deliberately ignore this part of their selves and live a life without the Force.

In Ahsoka’s case, did she indeed renounce the Jedi way at minimum? Did she renounce the Force altogether?

By the time of the events of *Rebels*, Ahsoka made her return as a de facto Jedi.

If she had renounced at least the Jedi way after leaving the Order, when did she return to it? Was it clear cut or was there some sort of full or partial transition over time? How did this “return as a Jedi” play out?

Comment: What makes you think she returned as a Jedi? She still uses the Force, and she knows how to fight and wield lightsabers, but that does not make her a Jedi if she renounced the Jedi way. There is no indication she is a Jedi, or pretending to be one. On the other hand, Kanan is a Jedi, because he chooses to continue following his teachings as best he can, and pass them along to Ezra.

Comment: I think the true answer will be in the newly announced Ahsoka novel.

Comment: Is there anyway I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 7):

I think we need to separate between the Jedi "alignment" (that is, associated with Light Side) against the Jedi (Order) "dogmas" (codes, rules, and teaching).

Ahsoka likely had abandoned many of the Jedi Order's dogmas, and thus is no longer a 'Jedi' (and she admitted as such in "Shroud of Darkness"). But, alignment-wise, she was still a 'Jedi'.

So I coined a term: *quasi-Jedi*, to describe people aligned with the Light Side but not fully subscribing to the Jedi Order dogmas.

Ahsoka is no longer a True Jedi, but she's still a quasi-Jedi.

Answer (score 3):

In the *Star Wars: Rebels* episode [*Shroud of Darkness*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shroud_of_Darkness), Ahsoka states that she no longer considers herself a Jedi.

> Because I am no longer a Jedi. It was my choice, I left the Order.

She says the same thing in *[Twilight of the Apprentice](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Twilight_of_the_Apprentice)*.

> I am no Jedi.

However, she did not renounce the Force, as she can be seen using it many times through the series.

Therefore, she can be best described as a non-Jedi Force-user who still tries to help people and do what's right.

Answer (score 2):

## She never renounced the Force

### Initially, Ahsoka abandoned the Jedi, but not the Force

After she left the Jedi Order, but before Order 66 and Palpatine’s takeover, Ahsoka was still on reasonably good terms with the Jedi Council, or at least willing to cooperate with them on a common goal. Indeed, they entrusted her with the mission of capturing Darth Maul, and she was willing to accept it.

> “**It was so nice of your former masters to send you out alone and spare
> me the exertion of a proper fight**,” Maul said. “You’re not even a real
> Jedi.”
>
> Malice dripped from his every word, and he bared his teeth at her. His
> was the kind of anger that Master Yoda warned the younglings about,
> the sort that ate a person whole and twisted every part of them until
> they were unrecognizable. Ahsoka shuddered to think what Maul must
> have suffered to become this way. Still, she was smart enough to use
> it to her benefit: she needed him angry enough to think he had the
> upper hand.
>
> “It’ll be a fair fight then,” she retorted, looking him up and down.
> “You’re only half a Sith.”
>
> That was rude for no reason, the type of thing that would’ve had
> Master Kenobi rolling his eyes, but Ahsoka couldn’t bring herself to
> regret it. Taunting one’s enemy was customary, and Ahsoka was going to
> use all the cards she was dealt, even if it wasn’t polite. **He was
> right, after all: she was no Jedi.**
>
> <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>

This serves as a strong indication that, despite Ahsoka’s disillusionment with the Jedi Order, she and the order shared enough mutual respect and sufficiently similar goals to be willing to work together. Notice, though, that even here, she’s emphatic that she is *not* a Jedi.

She’s still using the Force:

> She reached out to the Force and found it waiting for her, a comfort
> and a source of power. She opened her mind to it and listened with
> every part of her that could.
>
> <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>

Still, it would seem that she may have given up her lightsabers upon leaving the Order:

> “Be careful, Ahsoka,” he’d told her, before handing over her
> lightsabers and running off to save the Chancellor. “Maul is tricky.
> And he has no mercy in him at all.”
>
> <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>

### After Order 66, she was more careful, but still followed the Force

Once Palpatine took over and killed all the Jedi, Ahsoka naturally was more cautious about open displays of Force power. She used her mundane skills to accomplish tasks, rather than su9ing the Force to enhance her talents as she might once have done:

> Hoping that no one could see her, she ran along the tops of the
> houses. Even with the danger, it felt better than anything Ahsoka had
> done in a long time. She didn’t use the Force to run—there was no
> point in taking unnecessary risks—but she did use it to make sure each
> jump across the streets below was safe.
>
> <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>

She still continued practices related to the Force though, such as meditation, as long as she could do so surreptitiously:

> From there, it was easy to fall into her meditation. For a moment she
> hesitated, afraid of what she’d seen—not seen—since the Jedi purge,
> but then she let herself go. Meditation was one of the things she
> missed most, and one of the few things that wasn’t likely to get her
> caught, even if someone saw her doing it.
>
> The Force felt different now, and Ahsoka wasn’t sure how much of the
> difference was her. By walking away from the Temple, from the Jedi,
> she had given up her right to the Force—or at least that’s what she
> told herself sometimes. She knew it was a lie. The Force was always
> going to be a part of her, whether she was trained or not, the way it
> was part of everything. She couldn’t remove the parts of her that were
> sensitive to it any more than she could breathe on the wrong side of
> an airlock. Her authority was gone; her power remained.
>
> <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>

It’s clear that even though she occasionally felt as though abandoning the Jedi meant abandoning the Force, the more sensible part of her realized that that was impossible. In any case, she still continued her meditations upon the Force. It seems very likely that during this period (about a year after Order 66), she did *not* continue her training in more active or flashy areas of the Force, for fear of exposure. She slacked off, in other words. But she still recognized the necessity of regular practice in order to keep her skills sharp:

> Using the Force was a natural extension of herself. Not using it all
> the time was strange. She would have to practice, really practice with
> proper meditation, or someday she would need her abilities and be
> unable to respond in time. She’d been lucky to escape Order 66, and
> her escape had not been without terrible cost. The other Jedi, the
> ones who had died, hadn’t been able to save themselves, powerful or
> otherwise.
>
> <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>

She lacked lightsabers at this point, though, having left them in order to persuade the newly minted Empire that she had been killed:

> Ahsoka held her lightsabers, her last physical connection to the Jedi
> and to her service in the Clone Wars. It was so hard to give them up,
> even though she knew she had to. It was the only way to sell the con
> of the false burial, and it would buy her a modicum of safety, because
> whoever found them would assume she was dead, too.
>
> <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>

### Later on, she took a more active role, and adopted her own philosophy

Over the course of the novel of the same name, starting about one year after the rise of the Empire, Ahsoka decides to step back into the game, as it were, and take a more active role.

> “In this fight, there will be people like Barriss who are focused on
> the past,” he said. “And there will be other people who focus strongly
> on the future. Neither of them is wrong, exactly, but even if we don’t
> always walk the same path as one another, ours must be the middle
> road.”
>
> Ahsoka smiled.
>
> “That’s what I thought when I was trying to find the crystals that
> power my lightsabers,” she told him. “I didn’t want to be alone, but I
> didn’t want to be a general or even a Padawan anymore. I want
> something in the middle of that, still useful but different than
> before.”
>
> <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>

She hasn’t been a Jedi for a while, as mentioned previously. But it’s here that she really strikes out and decides to form a unique outlook on the Force. She sees the flaws in what the Jedi Order was, and prefers to find her own way:

> “I’m not a Padawan anymore, Senator, and it’s not safe to be Ahsoka
> Tano,” she said. “Barriss Offee was wrong about a lot of things. She
> let her anger cloud her judgment and she tried to justify her actions
> without considering their wider effects. She was afraid of the war and
> she didn’t trust people she should have listened to. **But she had a
> point about the Republic and the Jedi. There was something wrong with
> them, and we were too locked into our traditions to see what it was.**
> Barriss should have done something else. She shouldn’t have killed
> anyone, and she definitely shouldn’t have framed me for it, but if
> we’d listened to her—really listened—we might have been able to stop
> Palpatine before he took power.”
>
> <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>

Her new attitude is symbolized by her adoption of a new pair of lightsabers: neither the blue or green of the Jedi nor the red of the Sith, but a neutral white.

This is the attitude that she has when she appears in *Rebels*. She’s no longer a Jedi, but she still follows and practices the Force. **She is not a “*de facto* Jedi,”** though she still seems to lean toward the light side. She’s rejected the ossification of Jedi tradition, and opted to find her own understanding of the Force. **She’s not even entirely light side anymore, either.**

How emphatically not a Jedi is she?

Well, she displays attachment, of course:

> AHSOKA: Anakin. I won’t leave you. Not this time.
>
> VADER/ANAKIN: Then you will die.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Rebels*, “Twilight of the Apprentice Part II”</sub>

**More importantly, she displays an unrepentant desire for *revenge***:

> VADER/ANAKIN: Anakin Skywalker was weak. I destroyed him.
>
> AHSOKA: **Then I will avenge his death.**
>
> ANAKIN: **Revenge is not the Jedi way.**
>
> AHSOKA: **I am no Jedi.**
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Rebels*, “Twilight of the Apprentice Part II”</sub>

And Anakin would know, wouldn’t he?

> ANAKIN: I shouldn’t have done that. It’s not the Jedi way.
>
> PALPATINE: [stands up, rubbing his wrists] **It is only
> natural. He cut off your arm, and you wanted revenge.** It wasn’t the
> first time, Anakin. Remember what you told me about your mother and
> the Sand People.
>
> <sub>*Revenge of the Sith*</sub>

Revenge is so much *not* the Jedi way, in fact, that [the title was changed](https://news.google.com/newspapers?id=88daAAAAIBAJ&sjid=mW0DAAAAIBAJ&pg=7030,5817004&dq=revenge-of-the-jedi&hl=en) from *Revenge of the Jedi* to *Return of the Jedi.* That Ahsoka espouses revenge is a definite sign that she has developed a philosophy very different from that of the Jedi, and which, while generally benevolent, is perhaps not even entirely of the light.

**In summary: Ahsoka gradually abandoned the ways of the Jedi Order, beginning with her actual departure from it. She returned as an ally, but never as a Jedi.  She also never stopped using the Force.**